# Database connectionto both local and online database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have an online database and what I need to do is to fetch data from it and save to my local database(localhost). I tried adding  remote mysql database cause it said it is needed(I added the IP address of my local computer), I dont know if its right. The problem is it gives me an error
"arning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.24.168.85' (4) in /home/umalert/public_html/server/_includes/connection.php on line 18
Database connection failed:".

For now I have this connection script:

```
// create database connection
$connection_local = mysql_connect('x.x.x.x:3306', 'xxx', 'yyy');
if(!$connection_local) {
    die ("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

// selece database to use
$db_select_local = mysql_select_db('umalert_db', $connection_local);
if(!$db_select_local) {
    die("Database connection failed: ". mysql_error());
}
```

Hope you can help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your mysql username/password... Plus, you're connecting to a 10.x.x.x IP... what do you mean, "remote"? If that IP address is NOT in your local network, then it's not connectable at all. the 10/8 IP block is for private networks and such addresses are **NOT** usable over the public internet.

Comment: Are you sure that username is allowed from every IP? Or maybe in user table it's allowed only from localhost? More: port 3006 is open on firewall?

Answer (score 1):

you should **export** your data from one database and **import** to another one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but, I need to do it in my php script.